# After click, reverse animation on jQuery (Show/Hide)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Effect in jQuery to make a div appear when a trigger is clicked, which it does very successfully. However I want the animation to reverse to make the div disappear, when that same trigger is clicked again. The effect I want to make is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML Example:

```
<section id="showmenu1" style="background-color:#09F; color:#fff">
    <h1>Show Div</h1>
</section>
<div class="menu1" style="display: none; background-color:#09F; color:#fff; padding:0; margin:0">
    <ul style="padding:0px; margin:0px; position: relative; text-align: center;">
        <li>
            <h1 style="margin-top:0">Hello Div</h1>
            <p style="margin-top:0">Div is shown</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#showmenu1').click(function() {
        $('.menu1').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wL71w8td/

Comment: Could you help with this? jsfiddle.net/x3L8uq19/2 Cheers, I'd like to make the arrow point down when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

ToggleSimply use slideToggle instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped along with the other comments.

Comment: Could you help with this? http://jsfiddle.net/x3L8uq19/2/ Cheers, I'd like to make the arrow point down when clicked.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, last one I promise. please see: http://jsfiddle.net/x3L8uq19/6/ When I click one 'show div', both the triangles change, could you help me with a quick fix please? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).hide("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 1000);
});
```